# Top level bodies of modules syntax error with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

My `await` for `asyncCall()` to finish in the `inputEntriesNotOnScreen` function does not work despite it being in an async function. I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

What does the second part of the error mean?

```
function resolve1MS() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 1);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  let clicked = false;
  while( !clicked){
    await resolve1MS();
    if($('.ui-menu-item').length != 0){
      $('.ui-menu-item')[0].click();
      clicked = true;
      $matrix = $("table.timesheet tbody tr");
      return {
        lastRow: $matrix.last()
      }
    }
  }
}

async function inputEntriesNotOnScreen($matrix, notFoundInInitialSearch){
  let lastRow = undefined;
  notFoundInInitialSearch.forEach(function(item, index){
    console.log(item, index);
    if( lastRow == undefined){
      lastRow = $matrix.last();
    }
    else{
      lastRow = await asyncCall();
    }
    lastRow.find('.search')[0].click();
    let $searchBar = $('.ui-autocomplete-input');multiple times
    $($searchBar[index]).val(item[0][0]);
    $searchBar[index].dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
  });
}
```

Comment: how are you calling `inputEntriesNotOnScreen`?

Comment: You are creating an inner function for the forEach which is not async. Replace the `forEach` with a `for` loop.

Comment: It's referring to ES2015 Module syntax. You are technically allowed to use `await` in the top level of modules, as opposed to having to write an async function. See [the proposal that made it happen](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await). It will be included in ES2022.

Comment: @AlbertoRivera thank you I was confused and forgot that I was actually creating another function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a function to pass to your `forEach` which is not `async`.

Replacing the `forEach` with a standard `for` loop should allow you to use `await` as needed.

As a heads up, if you make the function in the `forEach` async, like `forEach(async function(item, index)`, you will be able to use `await` inside the function, but all the callbacks will be ran in parallel (after reaching the await), and you won't have a way to wait for them.

https://jsfiddle.net/8nwdus0h/

For more information, you can read [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)